# Passar de uma funcão para outra

Tags: php

Tenho duas funções em uma classe, como fazer para pegar o valor de uma variável que esta dentro de uma função e aproveitar esse mesmo variável em outra função da mesma classe.  Quero tornar a variavel  $userFullname Global para cer usada em toda classe.

```
public function GetHtml($data)
{

    $this->data = $data;
    $quizinfo   = $this->data['quizinfo'];
    $quizinfo   = (object) $quizinfo;           

    foreach ($this->data['users'] as $key => $user) {

        $userFullname = $user['firstname'] . $user['lastname'];  
    }
```

Comment: Torne essa variável (local) em um membro da classe

Comment: Você tem **duas funções** na classe ou tem **dois métodos**. Precisa ser mais claro. Se possível, coloque o código para nós analisarmos

Comment: Humberto, só para entender a diferença: `funções` são trechos de códigos reutilizáveis, são declaradas independente de classe. `métodos` são as "funções" que você define numa classe. Só para entender as nomeclaturas

Answer (score 3):

Torne essa variável local, em um membro da classe para fazer isso basta definir ela logo após o nome da classe.

```
class usuario{
   private $userFullname; //<--- definição do membro da classe

   public function GetHtml($data){
      $this->data = $data;
      $quizinfo   = $this->data['quizinfo'];
      $quizinfo   = (object) $quizinfo;     

      foreach ($this->data['users'] as $key => $user) {
         //aqui a atribuição mudou
         $this->userFullname = $user['firstname'] . $user['lastname'];
      }
```

Detalhe isso é apenas o techo de códifo fornecido na pergunta, então `userFullname` sempre terá o último usuário da lista, se deseja armazenar a lista completa use colchetes na atribuição `$this->userFullname[] = 'algo';`

Comment: Assim ele terá sempre de executar o método `GetHtml` antes de aceder à propriedade `$userFullname`

Answer (score 2):

```
class usuario() {
     public $userFullname;

     public function __construct($data) {
         $this->userFullname = $this->GetHtml($data);
     }

     protected function GetHtml($data) {
         $this->data = $data;
         $quizinfo   = $this->data['quizinfo'];
         $quizinfo   = (object) $quizinfo;     

         foreach ($this->data['users'] as $key => $user) {
            $userFullname = $user['firstname'] . $user['lastname'];
         }
         return $userFullname;
     }

}

$user = new usuario($data);
echo $user->userFullname;
```

Assim ficará disponível sempre que for criada uma instância do objecto `usuario`, escusa de executar antes o `GetHtml();`